Debug swap-oob on a script tag
I have this at the end of response to an hx-get request
<script src="/core/misc/dropbutton/dropbutton.js?v=10.2.4" hx-swap-oob="beforeend:body"></script>

</body>
</html>

Using the debug extension on the body tag, I can see the htmx:oobBeforeSwap and htmx:oobAfterSwap events in console, and the events seem to target the right things.  When HTMX is all done, the script tag is not in the DOM.  How can I debug or refine this approach?

You need to wrap the script tag around div, since (in your case)  the oob grabs inner content.
<div hx-swap-oob="beforeend:body">
    <script src="/core/misc/dropbutton/dropbutton.js?v=10.2.4"></script>
</div>


Happy to try that but help me reconcile your suggestion with the documentation. Why would swap be using innerHtml if I'm specifying beforeend?

I think the "swap" relates to swapping method on the target html, but when it's "extracted" from the response, it seems to take inner content, when you don't have ID specified and outer if ID exists. I stand corrected if I'm wrong, but I noticed this behaviour when testing oob myself. I could not find any detailed info in the docs. Sorry. Are you able to confirm that? or maybe this is happening for script tags only for some reason.. Have you tried testing oob with normal div and see what happens?

Thanks for the additional explanation.  I'll experiment and let you know what I find

Thank you!  I added a static <div> with the same hx-swap-oob property wrapping a <p> to my response, and when HTMX processed the response, I had just the <p> tag and it's contents before the end of the body.

It looks like your response element is missing the selector/ID of the element it's intended to replace.
<script
  id="thing-being-replaced"
  src="/core/misc/dropbutton/dropbutton.js?v=10.2.4"
  hx-swap-oob="beforeend:body"
></script>

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/

If a selector is given, all elements matched by that selector will be swapped. If not, the element with an ID matching the new content will be swapped.



any valid hx-swap value, followed by a colon, followed by a CSS selector

beforeend:body My selector is intended to be body and my swap strategy is intended to be beforeend.  How am I mis-understanding the documentation?
